# Hidden form field not created

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create an HIDDEN field titled EMPLOYEES_id in Code Igniter. I've looked at the docs and have followed them, But the field just isnt going in.

My code is as a follows..

```
<?php $EMPLOYEES_id = array('EMPLOYEES_id' => $message[0]->EMPLOYEES_id); ?>
<?php $attributes = array('class' => 'well form-horizontal');?>
<?=form_open('messages/create', $attributes, '',$EMPLOYEES_id)?>
```

The field is not appearing in my form. I'm assuming that is because of an additional array being added to the `form_open`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two changes to suggest:

- The hidden field array is supposed to be the third parameter, not the fourth.
- Try performing a full `<?php echo` instead of the `<?=` [shortcut syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php):

Comment: Nothing at all. Just not loading it in.

Comment: Managed it myself. I used <?=form_hidden($EMPLOYEES_id);?>

Answer (score 0):

If you still wanted to try the form_open method, then firstly, follow Yan's idea as the array is meant to be the third parameter, not the fourth.

Secondly, as you're passing two classes it might be the case that CodeIgniter doesn't like this.

Perhaps try:

```
$attributes = array('class' => 'well', 'class' => 'form-horizontal');
```

too. Though I more than suspect this isn't the issue, but it's got to be worth a shot...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Your code:

```
<?=form_open('messages/create', $attributes, '',$EMPLOYEES_id)?>
```

The hidden input is the third parameter, you are passing it as the forth, it should be:

```
<?=form_open('messages/create', $attributes, $EMPLOYEES_id)?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$initial_pump = array(
                    'name' => 'EMPLOYEE_id',
                    'id' => 'EMPLOYEE_id',
                    'value' => $message[0]->EMPLOYEES_id)
                );
echo form_hidden($initial_pump);
```